# Can we modify the android TV operating system?

Tags: android, operating-system, android-tv

I am making android tv application i want to know that can we modify the operating system of that , if it is possible please tell me. Due to some problem i need some changes in operating system is it possible. Can we change android TV operating system according to our needs.

Comment: so how do you imagine this? You make some OS changes and Google will apply your changes via an update to all their devices? You have to contact Google with this proposal though I'm pretty sure this would be a waste of time

Comment: i can think this, because android is open source may be by some trick or modification it may be possible.

Comment: see https://source.android.com/source/contributing.html

Comment: that link is very good ,but dear they didn't mention information about the tv operating system and their modification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to reword your question to make it clear. From what i understand, the answer is no, you cannot change the android OS as a application developer

Comment: sir, i am making an app for android tv , due to some problem i need some changes in operating system is it possible.

Comment: No, you CANNOT change the operating system. you can only use its api to create your apps.

Comment: how can i get full information about that could you tell me? i have search lot of time on google but i didn't get any result.

Comment: @rohitsharma http://android.stackexchange.com may be a good place

Comment: @rohitsharma "Developing/programming for Android" is [off-topic at that site](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), I'm just guessing that it _may be_ useful place to turn to. Asking your the device vendor (the one who manufactures and installs and flashes the TVs for whom you're creating the code) would be probably the best option